# IE 8 Visited Links shift right

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have created a site and it looks great in every browser except IE8, there it appears that the links, when visited shift right and the clickable area migrates away from the text. Is there any easy way to fix this?

Site is online here:
http://serif.cz/clients/bikram/

Answer (score 2):

It appears this CSS rule `#fade A:link, A:visited` is causing the problem because the 2nd part is applying the rule to all anchor tags.

Change it to...

`#fade A:link, #fade A:visited`

Comment: thank you, so, so, so much! That was driving me crazy. Such a small thing can really ruin the whole site.